# Mac Pgadmin4 - Fatal error - The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted

Tags: pgadmin

When I try to launch Pgadmin4 i am getting fatal error "The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted. This is happening only after installing postgres. Initially i was having only pgadmin. Later I installed PostgresSql server. From then onwards i am getting this error on launching pgadmin.[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hAAL.png)

I tried the following solutions but no luck

1. Tried launching pgadmin4 after stopping postgres server.
2. Tried with the different port